# api.stormpath rest json post data for loginAttempts method

Tags: ajax, json, web-services, api, stormpath

am new on stormpath api. i read documents for the create application & User.and i did it successfully.

now, i want to authenticate or validate user using web services.for that my code is

```
var Result = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(bytes)));


        var postData = { "type": "basic", "value": Result };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/ApplicationID/loginAttempts",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(postData),
            success: function (response) {

                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (ErrorResponse) {
               alert(ErrorResponse.statusText);
            }


        });
```

Now, here always i am getting "error" on errorresponse. and when i check on browser console, it's show authoried error.

so, kindly let me know what step i am missing.

also, i download the secure key value file & put on the root.
i am calling from my localhost. so, that's why is it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Stormpath API does not support calls from native clients (such as the browser), but that feature is coming soon!  In the meantime I would suggest creating a lightweight server to sits between your front-end application and our API.  We have SDKs and sample apps for many languages and frameworks, check out the docs for more info: https://docs.stormpath.com/home/

Comment: Hi check  "Authenticate a User Account" on https://docs.stormpath.com/home/. at here they explain to make a call from browser. but why its  not working for me that's point.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?  It is the correct answer.  Can you please point out where the docs claim to support browser-based calls for user authentication?  This way it can be cleaned up if it does not represent something accurately.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, yes "robert" is right...i checked doc. now, have you anything which i can use on .net language to call stormpath api?
I checked on link but there is no SDK available for .net. or any another way for rest api?